# LINQ query using EF Core throws translation exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query that works if I'm using Entity Framework for .NET Framework:

```
var results = (from cp in ctx.CardPlacement
                             .SelectWhere(x => x.Created <= request.Request.EndDate && x.Created >= request.Request.StartDate)
               group cp by cp.Created.Date into batch 
               let firstCp = batch.First()
               select new SummaryResult
                          {
                              Id = firstCp.Id,
                              AltId = firstCp.AltId,
                              Created = firstCp.Created,                                       
                              PlacedValue = batch.Sum(x => x.Amount).ToString(),
                              Placement = (int)firstCp.AltId,
                              DatePlaced = firstCp.Created.DateTime                                       
                          }).ToList();
```

But when I use it in Entity Framework Core on .NET Core I get an exception:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: CONVERT(date, c.Created),
> ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: CardPlacement
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> ' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in Entity Framework.

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Comment: Yeah EFC is notorious for not being able to translate group by Linq queries that EF can

Comment: Please look for the countless questions on this issue on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GertArnold - I have looked for an example of the same issue, but I have not found one.  Would you please send a link to one of the countless question on this issue that you've located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```cs
var palcements = cp.CardPlacement
    .Where(x => x.Created <= request.Request.EndDate && x.Created >= request.Request.StartDate);

var grouped = 
    from p in palcements
    group p by p.Created.Date into g
    select new 
    {
        CreatedDate = g.Key,
        Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    };

var query =
    from d in grouped
    from firstCp in palcements
        .Where(p => p.Created.Date == d.CreatedDate)
        .OrderBy(p => p.Created)
        .Take(1)
    select new SummaryResult
    {
        Id = firstCp.Id,
        AltId = firstCp.AltId,
        Created = firstCp.Created,                                       
        PlacedValue = d.Amount.ToString(),
        Placement = (int)firstCp.AltId,
        DatePlaced = firstCp.Created.DateTime                                       
    };
```

Note that in EF Core 6 your query should work.